# Choices for flagging question are not available

Tags: support, questions, flags

I wanted to flag a question and I had only 3 choices:

1. it needs ♦ moderator attention
2. it is spam
3. it is not welcome in our community

Before today, I could chose

1. not a real question
2. off topic
3. ...

Why the original choices are not available ?

I wanted to flag this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826861/i-have-a-function-written-in-php-i-want-to-convert-that-in-to-java-can-some-one

Comment: Did you try to do this before or after the question was voted closed?

Comment: When I asked the question here, the question on SO wasn't closed.

Comment: @Makoto The question is deleted. Now, I'm not sure at 100% that the question was closed. My memory is not very good :-) I wanted to see the timestamp when the question was closed to compare when I flagged it.

Comment: If it was closed before you flagged it, then @BoltClock's answer applies.  If not, then that is a bit of a weird issue - and I would try to reproduce it on another question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "it does not belong here" category of flags consists of flags for closure; that is, flags that alert moderators (and 10k-rep users) to questions that need to be closed for whichever reason that is chosen. The options in that category (and in fact the entire close flagging UI) are identical to the close reasons you will have access to [when you reach 3k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions).

Since the question you link to has already been closed since you first accessed the flags dialog, there is no reason to let users flag it for closure anymore, so the system simply hides that flag category, leaving you with the other choices.

Comment: While you are still able to flag closed questions using the "it needs ♦ moderator attention" option, **please don't use that flag option if you're *only* going to tell us that it was closed for whatever reason**, because those flags are useless to us since the questions have already been closed.